# Scaffolding con ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

He estado trabajando recientemente con *ASP.NET 5*, adicional a las nuevas características que tiene y las mejoras que hace no logro encontrar la forma de hacer *scaffolding* como se hacía en *ASP.NET 4*.

¿Hay algún complemento funcional y estable para un proyecto de *ASP.NET 5* o esta funcionalidad estará disponible para versiones posteriores?

Comment: Exactamente a que escafolding te refieres? EN asp.net 5 RC1 Hay scafolding para Controllers de MVC 6 y para Web API con EF

Comment: Esto puede ayudar https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/811973ed-e6a9-4f38-b375-2fee9931bebd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En ASP.NET 5, el Scafolding estará soportado oficialmente y se podrá realizar de dos maneras:

- [Desde Visual Studio](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html?highlight=scaffolding#create-a-data-model-and-scaffolding)
- [Desde la línea de comandos](https://chad.tolkien.id.au/asp-net-vnext-mvc6-ground-up-4-crud-in-mvc/)

En el repositorio de GitHub de ASP.NET 5 hay un proyecto específico para [Scafolding](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding) que está en pleno desarrollo.

También es interesante leer el [Issue #135](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/135) de ese mismo proyecto, en el que [@sayedihashimi](https://twitter.com/sayedihashimi) aporta detalles sobre el progreso y se puede ver como actualmente se están centrado en el Scafolding basado en Visual Studio.

En cuanto al progreso del Scafolding basado en comandos se puede seguir en el [Issue #139](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/139)

Comment: también podrías utilizar un generador llamado yeoman http://yeoman.io/ para ello debes instalar NodeJS (https://nodejs.org/) ya que utiliza el manejador de paquetes "npm" lo instalas de manera global "npm install -g yo" y luego en la consola escribes: "yo". Le instalas el generador de ASPNET https://github.com/omnisharp/generator-aspnet#readme y a disfrutar la programación!

Comment: @fredyfx tienes razón en lo que dices de Yeoman pero creo que la pregunta se refiere al Scafolding azanzado que se hace desde el modelo de datos y que comento en mi respuesta. Yeoman es mas para crear  el proyecto desde cero, e ir añadiendo elementos y con la extensión de VSCode va fenomenal

Comment: Gracias @rsciriano, aportando al comentario, debo decir que yeoman no necesariamente va para proyectos desde cero, también puede utilizarse un subgenerador (dentro de yeoman) para hacer el Scafolding los controladores solamente.